# PhpStorm regular expression search and replace it

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm, this is I want to search and modify content.

```
<img src="/images/test1.png" class="bar" />
<img src="/images/test2.jpg" id="test" />
<div id="content">
    <img src="/assets/images/test3.png" />
</div>
```

I want add a helper into the src path. After modify

```
<img src="<?php helper_src('/images/test1.png'); ?>" class="bar" />
<img src="<?php helper_src('/images/test2.jpg'); ?>" id="test" />
<div id="content">
    <img src="<?php helper_src('/assets/images/test3.png'); ?>" />
</div>
```

I used the regular expression to find it `<img src=(\'|\")\/.*\.(jpg|png)`, how can I use `Replace in Path` to replace all my search result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the following (slightly modified) regular expression:

```
<img src=(?:\'|\")(?<path>\/.*\.(?:jpg|png))(?:\'|\")
```

you can use the below "replace" value:

```
<img src="<?php helper_src('$1'); ?>
```

It contains a template that you described, and `$1` puts the first matched group (it is called `path`) into it.